# clipToPadding attribute ignored on android 5 (API 21)

Tags: android, scrollview, android-5.0-lollipop

Does clipToPadding attribute work on API 21? As you can see in the example below it does not.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:padding="24dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2000dp"
            android:background="#fee57f" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

[image]